# All my keys are shortcuts to the power button

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 21.04

I just installed Ubuntu 21.04 on my new computer (ROG Strix RTX 3060, Ryzen 7).

My problem is that as soon as I press a key (except for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ ... ), it offers me to turn off my computer. It is as if all my keys are shortcuts to the power button.

Moreover, when I deactivate the power button, I don't have this problem anymore. However, there is a latency, which confirms that pressing a key doesn't only write the letter.

Can someone help me?